# Term for a person who is from the same college or university as yours?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

If two American strangers (or for that matter any nationals) are **compatriot** for each other What is equivalent of a person who is from the same college or university as yours?

See below example:

Somboon to Jim: Hi, Do you like the Philippines?

Jim to Somboon: Hi, we liked Philippines a lot. Jack and me are compatriots. We are US citizen. So we like to travel different countries.

Somboon to Jim: Oh you are from the same country, but you look different. I thought you are Filipino.

Jim to Somboon: No I am not. But Jack and me are in fact ___________ (from same college).

Comment: How about "fellow alumnus"/"fellow alumni"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collegemate](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/collegemate) :

> A person from the same college.

(Wiktionary)

Or [classmate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/classmate) if you are

> a member of the same class at a school or college.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Is "Fellow-collegian" or "Co-collegian" a possibility.

Comment: @AMN - yes, “fellow collegian” is used - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fellow%20collegian%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1982,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl, whike co-collegian is not.

Comment: Neither is in standard usage. Also, neither specifically designates the compatriot as being from the _same_ university. Indeed, the least awkward situation to use "fellow collegian" would be at an event attended by students from multiple colleges where one might say something like, "Today you and your fellow collegians embark on new chapter...."

Comment: A classmate would have to be in the same class, and hence attend at the same time as you. OP hasn't stated whether that is a problem or not, but it sounds like an unnecessary narrowing of scope to me.

Answer (score 1):

This use is common in American English so can't speak for British English or otherwise, but sometimes you may hear the phrase *sharing an **Alma Mater***.

> Jim and I *share an **Alma Mater***, so it's interesting that after some years we'd come to work at the same place after college and meet again.

**Alma Mater** is Latin for *nourishing mother*, and is a term used to refer to the higher education institute one graduates from, with a certain degree of fondness. Two people who have gone to the same university (and, subsequently, graduated from), for example, are then said to *share an **Alma Mater***.

Answer (score 1):

Some U.S. colleges have relatively well-known nicknames for their students, so if you’re writing fiction, you can draw on these. For example two graduates of Syracuse University *might* choose to refer to themselves as *we’re both Orangemen*. This wouldn’t work in the dialog you use as an example, since it usually requires the third person to be familiar with that general sector of the U.S. college sports scene, but in a different context it might be useful.

In general, it would be far more common to say *at the same school* or *went to the same college*, unless you are striving for an overeducated, pretentious, and somewhat “precious” effect.